# SOAP Messages through JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, apache, proxy

This is an issue others have written about but I've not been able to understand the solutions proposed.

I have a very simple Java WebService server running on my local computer. I'm developing it for a game I'm making.

I'm creating it using javax.jws.WebService and publishing it using javax.xml.ws.Endpoint as per the tutorial here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-eclipse-javase1/

I'm publishing it on my local computer along the lines of:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://MyComputerName:8080/subserver", new SubServer());
```

I've forwarded port 8080 on my router, and I have a static IP address. Externally I can view the WSDL without a problem.

My issue is, I want to call the methods of my WebService from within a JavaScript Canvas game I'm writing. Whenever I make a request I get no response and the following error on the server:

```
Mar 03, 2012 9:39:24 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler handleExchange
WARNING: Cannot handle HTTP method: OPTIONS
```

So Chrome is not doing a POST request as I asked, but is doing an OPTION request because apparently I'm doing a cross-domain request. I'm not sure how I am doing a cross-domain request when all of my files are on the same server (my local computer).

Is the problem that I am posting an Endpoint of MyComputerName... but then the incoming request is to MyExternalIPAddress... ? Is that why it is considered a cross-domain request?

I've looked at different options including JSONP which I didn't understand (and I don't think my WebService supports it anyway) but I think my best option is to set up a proxy server - but without understanding WHY I am doing a cross-domain request I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing.

I'd be very grateful for anyone who could help me understand what's going on here and/or help me find a solution. So frustrating. I've spent a good 6 hours today trying to solve this without any luck.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem and understand the root cause of the issue. Modern web browsers don't let the XMLHttpRequest object send requests to any server other than the one the page was requested from. What I had to do was set up Apache HTTP Server as a Reverse Proxy. Now my page is requested from myserver:80/index.html and the SOAP requests go to myserver:80/mySoapName - and Apache re-directs the SOAP calls to my WebService. You need to use mod_proxy and mod_proxy_html and add ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse etnries to httpd.conf.

Comment: Please don't answer your own question in a comment. Please post this as an answer instead.

Comment: n00ber: cdeszaq is right. Probably you don't have enough reputation but as soon as you have please answer your own questions when that's the case. Nice work! http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/